# Please explain $E[S_{min(n,T)} ]= E [S_{0}]=0$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, random-walk

If $S_{n}$ is a simple random walk i.e $X_{k}= +/- 1$ with prob = 0.5

T = inf {n > = 0 |$S_{n}$ = 1} is a stopping time. T is finite almost surely.

.Explain $E[S_{min(n,T)} ]= E [S_{0}]=0$

I know that  $E[S_{T}] = 1 $, but I can't see the above , Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the [optional stopping theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optional_stopping_theorem) for bounded martingales.

In more details, apply the theorem to the bounded martingale
$(S_{\inf(t,n)})_{t\ge 0}$.